# Selenium ruby script fails with chromedriver while running it headless

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run a selenium ruby file (.rb) through command prompt in linux. I just need to launch chrome and get a url. So I downloaded and have Selenium-serverstandalone-2.37.0.jar and chromedriver (extracted from chromedriver_linux(32)) in the same directory (/home/). And I have set my path pointing to chromedriver also. I'm a starter, so pl let me know if I'm missing something here.

This is my test.rb file:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"
include RSpec::Expectations

describe "TestScript" do

  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
    @base_url = "http://www.google.com"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 5
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit
    @verification_errors.should == []
  end

  it "test_script" do
    @driver.get(@base_url)
    puts "Logged in"
    if(element_present?(:link, "Home"))
    puts "Home page is detected"
  end
   puts "Logging out"
 end

def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
end

def verify(&blk)
  yield
  rescue ExpectationNotMetError => ex
  @verification_errors << ex
end
```

Whe I run it, it throws this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'quit' for Nil:NilClass occured at /home/test.rb

 Failure/Error: @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
 Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
 Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your path.
```

Please guide me how to proceed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working!! Switching to older version of selenium-standalone-server did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It is not enough to place the `chromedriver` executable in the same directory. You have to make sure that it is in a directory that is in your `$PATH`. You could put it in `/usr/local/bin` and make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in `$PATH`.

You can check if `/usr/local/bin` already is in your `$PATH` with

```
echo $PATH | grep "/usr/local/bin"
```

if this outputs nothing, you need to add the following line to your shell config (e.g. `~/.bashrc` if you're using Bash):

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

then restart your shell and check again.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I added the chromedriver for linux in the $PATH. But still I'm getting the same error!

Comment: Can you please suggest me more improvements?